# How to travel session id to HTML pages

Tags: html, django, session

I am planing to travel my session id to all my HTML pages.Here i am creating session id and getting that using sessionId = request.session.session_key
After this how to send my session id to all my HTML pages.Is there any example code then that would be better.

Thanks,
Ram.

Answer (score 1):

The session is automatically available in all views. You don't need to send it in the query string:

> Session IDs in URLs
>
> The Django sessions framework is entirely, and solely, cookie-based.
>   It does not fall back to putting session IDs in URLs as a last resort,
>   as PHP does. This is an intentional design decision. Not only does
>   that behavior make URLs ugly, it makes your site vulnerable to
>   session-ID theft via the “Referer” header.

All you have to do, is make sure the session hasn't expired:

```
def home(request):
  foo = request.session.get('foo')
  if not foo:
     print('Oops! Session has expired. Do something')
  else:
     print('Session is still valid, value of foo is {}'.format(foo))
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'foo': foo})
```

Have a read of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/), sessions in django are very straightforward.